# Как установить Windows 11?

Tags: windows

У меня сейчас Windows 9 и хочу сделать Windows 11

Comment: Чего Windows 9, по-моему, такой версии не было. И причём тут android?

Comment: @gord1402, такая версия винды была: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_9x

Comment: @Глеб не кажется ли вам, что 9 и 9x это немножко не одно и то же?

Comment: То самое чувство, когда даже у Microsoft нет Windows 9, а у тебя есть. Дашь ссылку на iso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 11 можно установить здесь: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows11